# Update context of a django custom view

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this view rendering a simple template with a context.

In this template I have a form to make an axios call to update the variables `first_name` and `last_name` .

The call is correctly working and the response is ok. But my context does not update.

How can I update my template context? Can I do this without re-render my template?

```
def myView(request)
    first_name = 'John'
    last_name = 'Doe'

    # Handling the axios call
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = json.loads(request.body)['email']
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        first_name = user.last_name
        last_name = user.first_name

    ctx = {'first_name'=first_name, 'last_name'=last_name} 

    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', ctx)
```

Comment: You will need to do this with JavaScript, since Django is the *backend*, it only provides a response, that response can not be changed.

Comment: I need to update my variables to use these with an include tag : `{% include 'snippet.html' with first_name=first_name %}` If I do so with javascript, my include tag can not get these variables.

Comment: The point is that the *include* tag is *not* transferred to the client, it is simply *rendered*. Once rendered only JavaScript is able to change the DOM.

Comment: Ok, so I have to think this differently. Thanks